# Do swift hashable protocol hash functions need to return unique values?

Tags: swift, unique, protocols, collision, hashable

I am working through an iOS swift Tetris tutorial* and have it completed and working.
But I am puzzled about one particular aspect - the Hashable protocol.
The function:

```
class Block: Hashable, Printable {
    [...]    
    var hashValue: Int { return self.column ^ self.row }
```

Rows go 0..9, and Columns 0..20. The notes says of this function "We return the exclusive-or of our row and column properties to generate a unique integer for each Block.". But my understanding is that 0^1 would be the same as 1^0, etc... I would like to know if it is a problem if the Hash function is not unique like this, or are collisions are generally OK? As I say, the application appears to work fine...

*https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collisions are *not* "generally OK". The underlying assumption is that the hash value of `x` is the hash value of `y` if and only if `x == y`. If you consider column 2, row 1 the same as column 1, row 2, then fine. But I don't think you do! The application may appear to work, but presumably you have done nothing that requires hashability - yet.

Comment: That is what I thought. I'm thinking perhaps the code works because the functions that require the hash just effect a single row or column at a time. Thanks for the help. -D

Comment: The question is what would happen if you had, say, a Dictionary whose keys are Blocks. They wouldn't work correctly because the hash value is used to locate the key - and it wouldn't be unique.

Comment: Dictionary keys CAN have collisions, and actual equivalence is checked (`==`) before returning the value. In fact, you can just flat return 0 and Dictionary will work just fine. That's not guaranteed to be fine for all code that uses `hashValue`, but `hashValue` is not required to guarantee uniqueness. You could hash a string based on the first letter, for instance. `hashValue` is not a substitute for `==` which is why `Hashable` requires `Equatable`

Comment: -1. Hash collisions should never cause bugs, as hash functions (generally) don't guarantee perfect hashing. The only guarantee that a hash function `h` gives is that `h(x) != h(y)` implies that `x != y`.

Comment: @matt Could you confirm whether Swift requires hash function to be perfect? I guess 'the underlying assumption' is a bit vague: this 'assumption' exists in Java to make dictionary lookup O(1) , but doesn't require the hash code to be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The application is working because it also implements the Equatable protocol:

```
func ==(lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool {
    return lhs.column == rhs.column && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.color.rawValue == rhs.color.rawValue
}
```